# Deleting an application key?

Tags: feature-request, api, api-key

There should be delete buttons on <s>stackapps.com/apps</s> https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/ so we can delete API-keys.

Or at least de-activate them? I mean, cancelled projects, etc...
A deletion button would be real handy.