# How to delete an OAuth (2.0) API key?

Tags: feature-request, status-planned, api-key

I created a couple of extra keys I don't need. Can I delete them? I don't see an option anywhere in the list or on the page for the key itself.

Comment: There is currently no way to delete an application (which this is the equivalent of); it's coming, but is a low priority.  There's no harm in extra keys laying around, really.

Comment: @KevinMontrose: That's right - and I can always edit the key and use it for the next app I start working on.

Comment: @KevinMontrose bump...?

Comment: Duplicate request: [Deleting an application key?](http://stackapps.com/questions/212/deleting-an-application-key)