# How to delete apps in StackApps?

Tags: support, api, api-key, registration

I have registered an app in Stack Apps. I am trying to delete it, but unable to find the solution. Is there a way to delete it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**You cannot do this.**

A [delete feature has been requested](https://stackapps.com/questions/212/deleting-an-application-key) and [requested again](https://stackapps.com/questions/2910/how-to-delete-an-oauth-2-0-api-key) (with [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) given about 3.5 years ago).

Register your desire for this by **immediately upvoting these posts**:

1. [Deleting an application key?](https://stackapps.com/questions/212/deleting-an-application-key)
2. [How to delete an OAuth (2.0) API key?](https://stackapps.com/questions/2910/how-to-delete-an-oauth-2-0-api-key)

(*Theoretically*, if those feature requests get enough upvotes, they might get some developer love.)

---

For now, if you really want to delete your app (there's probably no real need to), you *might* try asking Stack Exchange directly via [the contact form](https://stackapps.com/contact).  Personally, I wouldn't bother for something this trivial.

---

Meanwhile, you can pseudo-disable your app by doing the following:

1. Reset your *Client Secret* [(Click for larger view):

   [image: client secret reset]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJ5GI.png)
2. Edit your app's settings to the following "safe" values:

   1. **Application Name:**   `**Delete me!**`
   2. **Description:**      `No can haz!`
   3. **OAuth Domain:**     `bad.invalid`   (Which is "guaranteed" bad per RFC 2606)
   4. **Application Website:**   `bad.invalid`
   5. **Application Icon (optional):**   leave blank/empty
   6. **Stack Apps Post (optional):**   leave blank/empty
   7. **Enable Client Side OAuth Flow:**   leave unchecked
   8. **Disable Desktop Application OAuth Redirect Uri:**   checked

Once you set those values, it will be ever-so-much harder for bad guys to hijack your app and do unspeakable evil with it. ;)

Comment: Planned since so many years. The vehicle is stuck.

Comment: still can't delete in 2024? wow