# Can I make a Private Application?

Tags: support, api-key, registration

I wish to access the API from a purely internal application; no visible app to the public, no promotion, no OAuth. That seems impossible via the key registration form; am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only is that possible, but we do it all the time.

- No one can see the apps you register at [stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register) except you (and the SE devs).
- **If you don't need OAuth**, then [you can enter just about any fake information in the required fields](https://stackapps.com/a/6406/7653).
  This still allows you to use the `key` to get 10K quota.

It is only when you want to access `private_info` or write to the site that you need OAuth and [a public post here](https://stackapps.com/questions/7/how-to-list-your-application-library-wrapper-script-here).

See, also: [My app has to be published first? But it's still under development](https://stackapps.com/questions/4573/my-app-has-to-be-published-first-but-its-still-under-development)

---

**If you *do* need OAuth**, your app/script post here does not have to link to your domain ([if any](https://stackapps.com/questions/7812/getting-an-api-key-for-an-application-without-a-server)).  So the public need not know anything other than that you have an app.

But beware that [there has been a backlash against stagnant or malformed app/script listings](https://stackapps.com/questions/7490/what-to-do-about-the-tsunami-of-placeholder-apps-created-because-of-a-poorly-wri).

---

Finally, if you **do not need OAuth, and you make less than 300 API calls** per day, per IP address, then you do not need to register your app at all.
The first and biggest benefit of registration is the increased quota.

Comment: So I add a key= to the request to pass along the key, and I get the quota?

Comment: Yes​‌​‌​‌​‌​‌​‌.