# I only need a key, what do I do?

Tags: support, faq, registration

I'm told by others and read in [Looking for a beginner's tutorial to using the API](https://stackapps.com/questions/4511/) that I need "To Get A Key!" but when I then visit https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register I'm stil uncertain how to proceed.

If I only need a key what is the shortest route to success without causing troubles for me, my app/script or others?

Answer (score 12):

When you click the [Register](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register) link you're presented with this webform:

[image: register app]

If you're in a hurry and click *Register your Application* you'll find this error:

[image: 4 fields required]

The fields Name, Description, Website URL and OAuth Domain are required.

You can probably dream up a name and a description but those pesky Website URL and OAuth Domain keep bugging me. Here is the shortest route to success:

| Field | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Application Name | CanHazKeyPls |
| Description | CanHazKeyPls |
| OAuth Domain | bad.invalid |
| Application Website | bad.invalid |

And now click on the big blue *Register your Application*.

Congrats, you now have registered an app. You find the key as the third item on your app registration page:

[image: app registration]

If you scroll all the way down you'll find a blue *Edit this App* button, allowing you to change any of the values you previously entered. So if you later do get an website or read-up on [Oauth flow](https://stackapps.com/questions/7857/what-exactly-is-a-valid-oauth-domain-name-for-registering-your-app) you can adapt your values accordingly.

Enjoy your new app and key!

<sup>credits for bad.invalid goes to Brock Adams in [his answer](https://stackapps.com/a/6406/18722)</sup>