# The fieldnames in the error message do not match the names used on the form

Tags: bug, meta, registration

When you register an app [here](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register) there are 4 fields that are required:

- Application Name
- Description
- OAuth domain
- Application Website

Leaving those fields empty returns this error message:

[image]
<sup>Image from [I only need a key, what do I do?](https://stackapps.com/questions/8971)</sup>

There is a mismatch between the naming of two fields in the error message compared to the actual form:

| Form | Error Message |
| --- | --- |
| Application Name | Name |
| Application Website | Website URL |

A minor issue is that the order the error messages don't match the order of the fields on the form.

If this is easy to fix with little chance on side-effects/impact can this be looked at?