# Download data for specific tag

Tags: support, tags, java, data-dump

How to download all the data just for a specific tag (say
[compiler-error])?
On Stack Overflow, there are around 19000 questions tagged with [compiler-error].
So, I was hoping is it downloadable w.r.t specific tags only?

Answer (score 1):

The `/questions` method supports this; you can limit your search by tag. Be sure to add the right output fields via a [filter](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters); in the example below, I've added `body`, `answers` and `answers.body` which are not included by default.

Here is the call for the first 100 questions: `https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#page=1&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=compiler-error&filter=!6VvPDzQ)wlg1u&site=stackoverflow&run=true`

You'll need to increase the page number [to get the rest](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/paging) and probably something to respect the [backoff / rate-limiting](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle). An [application key](https://stackapps.com/q/8971/34061) is also a good idea.

Finally, these kind of dumps can also be obtained (perhaps more easily) via the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/). It has an awesome [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) to help you get started (with the Data Explorer and with SQL in general).